# Cannot get firebase on child_added to work

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have gotten Firebase to work with React, but now I'm trying to do it in a basic website. For some reason, I can't get it to work. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();

  rootRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot){
    console.log('yolo');
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  })
</script>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get it so that if I add information to the database, it is displayed in the browser console. Here's what's weird, it only works if I push data to the database from the app. It doesn't work if I create a new child in the Firebase console. How do I fix this?

Comment: Check the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data#child-events

Comment: Are you sure your client has read permission on the data? By default only authenticated users have read access. See this documentation page to learn how to detect such read permission problems: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/23610/detecting-errors-when-reading-data-in-javascript#t=201609291923291087821

Answer (score 0):

Child events I think are restricted to Firebase lists, so a `push()` will trigger the `child_added`. On the Firebase console, the problem is that I don't know if there is a way to add an empty object in a list THEN populate it with child nodes. The only way I've been able to simulate a `push()` is to type in the console path to where the object should be in the browser and then add the child key/value pairs there.

So if you had a list at:

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/super-secret/database/data/list-of-games
```

You can type something like this to create a new `list-of-games` object:

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/super-secret/database/data/list-of-games/1234
```

This will create a child node for the list with the id 1234.

Hope this helps.